# $a_n=2^n+3^n+6^n-1$. Find all positive integers that are primes to all terms of the sequence.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let the sequence $a_n=2^n+3^n+6^n-1, n\in\mathbb N_{> 0}$. Find all positive integers that are prime to all terms of this sequence. I have no idea how to approach this, but I know that I CAN'T use Euler's theorem or any generalization/extension of fermat's little theorem as it's on a later chapter in the textbook.

If possible, fully explain all steps.

Comment: let $n$ be a $p-2$, where $p$ is a prime greater than 3 and use fermat's little theorem

Comment: This was a 2005 IMO problem.

Comment: The key insight is that $\frac12 + \frac13 + \frac16 - 1 = 0$; but this should be understood as an equality in the field $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The Aos related forum thread: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h44573p282138.

Answer (score 5):

If $n=2$, $a_n=48$.

Now let $p$ be a prime greater than $3$, and $n=p-2$. Using Fermat's little theorem,
$$
2^{p-2}+3^{p-2}+6^{p-2}-1\equiv 1/2+1/3+1/6-1=0 \;(mod\; p)
$$
So in the sequence we have all the primes, meaning the only positive integer prime to all $a_n$ is $1$

Answer (score 2):

Thought it could be useful to cite the solution from *The IMO Compendium A Collection of Problems Suggested for The International Mathematical Olympiads: 1959-2009*:

> We will show that $1$ is the only such number. It is sufficient to prove that for every prime number $p$ there exists some $a_m$ such that $p \mid a_m$. For $p=2,3$ we have $p\mid a_2=48$. Assume now that $p>3$. Applying Fermat's theorem, we have 
>   $$
> 6a_{p-2}=3\cdot 2^{p-1}+2\cdot 3^{p-1}+6^{p-1}-6\equiv 3+2+1-6=0 \pmod{p}.
> $$
>   Hence $p \mid a_{p-2}$, i.e. $\gcd(p,a_{p-2})=p>1$. This completes the proof.

Notice this is very similar to @Exodd's answer, although it avoids fractions.